# Is it possible to match against the result of a `const fn`?

Tags: rust, pattern-matching, constants

I've tried the naive approach

```
fn main() -> Result<(), Box<std::error::Error>> {
    let num = 0;
    match num {
        u64::max_value() => println!("Is u64::max_value()"),
        _ => println!("Is boring")
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

but it fails with `expected tuple struct/variant, found method <u64>::max_value`.

Is there another syntax except `n if n == u64::max_value() => ...` which can I use?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The left part of `=>` must be a pattern, and few expressions are also valid patterns. A call-expression is not a valid pattern.

Named constants can be matched so you can do this:

```
fn main() -> Result<(), Box<std::error::Error>> {
    let num = 0;

    const MAX: u64 = u64::max_value();
    match num {
        MAX => println!("Is u64::max_value()"),
        _ => println!("Is boring")
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

[Link to playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=dc5e6b24f7cc502a440499002512cc5c)

This also has the advantage of letting the compiler check whether your matching is exhaustive (which pattern guards [don't](https://gist.github.com/3fb1399288d6f24b3fefdac7dd4969e2)):

```
const fn true_fn() -> bool { true }

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<std::error::Error>> {
    let num = true;

    const TRUE: bool = true_fn();
    match num {
        TRUE => println!("Is u64::max_value()"),
        false => println!("Is boring")
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

[Link to playground](https://gist.github.com/236ce9187bc35a817ad5b523907ca9b3)

Comment: But it is not possible to use a `const fn`-call directly as pattern?

Comment: No, there is no `some::path()` pattern as there is a `some::path()` expression.

Comment: This problem is conceptual. Are you going to create variables for other cases like for example (min value, mid value, or some value, etc...)  ? If i have to use like this there is no point to use matcher.

Comment: You already have `std::u64::MAX`. You don't need to create your own binding.

Comment: @ÖmerErden For such a simple example, you don't need a binding sure (especially since one already exist as Boiethios reminded us), but there are more complicated examples where I'd definitely use constant items. Eg. I have a sensor were the raw value has to be scaled differently on 5 different intervals to get the actual value, then I created a constant for the 3 mid values. `const`s in Rust come at no cost, don't be afraid to use them.

Comment: This is a valid answer to the question, but IMO this should be fixed by the Rust team.

Comment: @TurtlesAreCute it's being worked on as part of [`const` expressions and patterns](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/76001). The syntax requires an explicit `const { … }` to disambiguate it and at the moment it requires a nightly compiler and explicitly enabled features but [it's already implemented to some extent](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ecbbfd41b7cd6f1a4af36c68ddbec3f7).